# Is 100% accuracy in DNA sequencing possible?

Tags: dna-sequencing, mitochondria

I would like to obtain a complete genome of a canine (with mitochondrial DNA too) at 100% accuracy. Is it even possible with the current technology? The source I have is potential degraded, i.e. dried saliva, dried blood, whisker root, fur roots, etc...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 100% accuracy. No technique is free of errors. Therefore we experiment a lot of times to improve the reliability.

Answer (score 2):

Current DNA sequencing techniques are based on [shotgun sequencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_sequencing), randomly breaking the chromosomes into small pieces, sequencing the pieces (by various techniques), and then computationally reassembling the pieces by looking for overlapping patterns. This depends on sequencing each piece of DNA multiple times; the more [coverage or depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_sequencing#Coverage), the more reliable the results. However, especially with long repeating base sequences, 100% coverage is uncommon with small genomes, and almost impossible with large genomes.